# <mutex> is not supported when compiling with /clr or /clr:pure

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winforms, opencv

i want to create a c++ opencv windows form in visual studio 2015 and used CLR form . when add opencv header files my form not run and show this message

**is not supported when compiling with /clr or /clr:pure.**

what can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Break up your code. Put the OpenCV includes in files that are compiled without clr and make some wrapper classes/functions that are exposed to the clr code.